# How to completely remove a package in Ubuntu (like it never existed)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, package-management, packages

When I remove a package in Ubuntu using `apt-get remove package`, it always seems to leave behind a lot of files... for example, log files in `/var/log`, config files in `/etc`, data in `/var/lib`, etc.

How do I COMPLETELY remove every trace of a package in Ubuntu, as if it never existed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should purge those packages.

```
apt-get purge somepackage
```

from man apt-get (`APT-GET(8)`)

```
   purge
       purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```

This is supposed to remove everything added by the package, such as config and data files. But I would assume it's possible that it generated something that is left behind anyway. `dpkg` doesn't track everything related to a package... and its cleanup scripts and such can be assumed to be imperfect and sometimes fail. Maybe it won't remove logs for example.

Comment: It should be noted that even purge does not remove e.g. config files in `~/.local`, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/151943/868447) over on askubuntu for a deeper dive.

Comment: `purge` will not remove files which were generated by the application, as opposed to the ones installed by `apt`. This includes the files generated indirectly, such as logs (which come from the app sending logging events to `/dev/log`, which is then parsed by another utility (`rsyslog`, ...)

Comment: @WoJ This depends on the package: For example, if a package logs directly to `/var/log/$package`, it's totally possible that this gets removed, if `purge` is requested. That is in contrast to anything in `$HOME` (as noted above), which `apt` must not touch, according to policy.